# Exact maximum likelihood estimation of MA(1)

Tags: r, time-series, estimation, maximum-likelihood, moving-average

I want to calculate the MLEs of the MA(1) model and for this purpose I have written the exact likelihood for the same. I built a programme in R for the log-likelihood, but it seems some problem in it whenever I use `nlm` function to optimize this. Here is my code in R.

```
rm(list = ls())
y <- c(2.33,2.84,6.09,4.25,2.56,5.69,7.59,2.19,7.08,3.1)
y=as.matrix(y)
T=length(y)
#psi=c(0.0054,0.045)
#psi=as.matrix(psi)
#q=length(psi)
#sigma=9.6
q=1

loglike=function(parm){

psi=parm[1];sigma=parm[2];

L=diag(rep(1,T));
for(i in 1:T){
if(i>q){psi[i]=0}
for(j in 1:T-1){
if((i+j)>T)break();
L[i+j,j]=psi[i]
}
}
L

B=diag(rep(psi[q]),q);
for(i in 1:q-1){
for(j in 1:q){
if((i+j)>q)break();
B[i,i+j]=psi[q-j]
}
}
B

O=matrix(0,T-q,q);
F=t(cbind(t(B),t(O)))

I=diag(rep(1),q)
D=I+(t(F))%*%(t(solve(L)))%*%(solve(L))%*%F
ehat=(solve(D))%*%(t(F))%*%(t(solve(L)))%*%(solve(L))%*%y
S=(t(y-F%*%ehat))%*%(t(solve(L)))%*%(solve(L))%*%(y-F%*%ehat)+(t(ehat))%*%ehat

loglike=-(T/2)*(log(6.28)+log(sigma))-(1/2)*solve(det(D))-(1/2*sigma)*S

return(-loglike)

}

nlm(loglike,c(0.0054,9.6),hessian=T)
```

Comment: What kind of problem (that you mentioned) is it?

Comment: http://econ.nsysu.edu.tw/ezfiles/124/1124/img/Chapter17_MaximumLikelihoodEstimation.pdf

Comment: http://stat.unicas.it/downloadStatUnicas/seminari/2008/Julliard0708_1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the matrix `L` is not properly defined since the error `solve.default(L)` is returned. Looking at the elements that you are using, the approach that it seems you are seeking can be sketched and implemented as follows (the following is based on Pollock (1999) [1] Chapter 22):

The logarithm of the likelihood function of the following moving average (MA) process 
$$
y_t = \varepsilon_t + \theta \varepsilon_{t-1} \,, \quad t=1,\dots,n \,,
\quad \varepsilon \sim NID(0, \sigma^2)
$$

is given by:

$$
L(y,\sigma^2) = -0.5 n \log(2\pi) - 0.5 \log(\sigma^2) - 0.5 \log(|Q_n|) -
\frac{y^\top Q_n^{-1}y}{2\sigma^2} \,,
$$

where $Q_n$ is the matrix of theoretical autocovariances of the MA process. By concentrating $\sigma^2$ out of the above expression, it can be seen that maximizing the log-likelihood function is equivalent to minimizing the following expression:

$$
S = \frac{y^\top Q_n^{-1}y}{n}|Q_n|^{1/n} \,.
$$

Now, the expression for $S$ can be evaluated as follows:

```
Q <- toeplitz(ARMAacf(ma = x, lag.max = n - 1) * (1 + theta^2))
Qinv <- chol2inv(chol(Q))
tmp <- drop(y %*% Qinv %*% cbind(y)) / n
Sval <- tmp * (det(Q))^(1/n)
```

First, we take advantage of the function `ARMAacf`, which returns the theoretical autocorrelations. Since the variance of a MA(1) process is $1 + \theta^2$, we can recover the autocovariances by multiplying those autocrrelations by $1 + \theta^2$. Then, as $Q$ is a symmetric matrix, it is more efficient to compute its inverse upon the Cholesky decomposition. Finally, we put all the elements together to evaluate the value of objective function $S$.

You can use this code to compare with the elements that you are using in your implementation.

---

Let's test this code in a small simulation exercise:

```
# objective function introduced above
Sfnc <- function(x, y, n)
{
  Q <- toeplitz(ARMAacf(ma = x, lag.max = n - 1) * (1 + x^2))
  tmp <- drop(y %*% chol2inv(chol(Q)) %*% cbind(y)) / n
  Sval <- tmp * (det(Q))^(1/n)
  Sval
}
# parameters of the simulation
niter <- 1000 # number of iterations
n <- 120 # sample size
ma <- 0.6 # MA coefficient of the data generating process
mres <- matrix(nrow = niter, ncol = 2) # matrix for storage of results
colnames(mres) <- c("Sfnc", "arima")
# main loop
set.seed(123)
for (i in seq_len(niter))
{
  # simulate a MA(1) of length 'n' and coefficient 'ma'
  y <- arima.sim(n = n, model = list(ma = ma))
  # minimize the objective function Sfnc
  mres[i,1] <- optimize(f = Sfnc, interval = c(-1, 1), y = y, n = n)$min
  # fit the same model using stats::arima
  mres[i,2] <- coef(arima(y, order = c(0,0,1), include.mean = FALSE))
}
```

As shown below, the results obtained with the method described above are in line with those estimates obtained by `stats::arima`:

```
# first parameter estimates for each method
head(mres)
# [1,] 0.7255807 0.7255885
# [2,] 0.6235342 0.6235284
# [3,] 0.6087424 0.6087536
# [4,] 0.4811465 0.4811588
# [5,] 0.5823097 0.5823167
# [6,] 0.6665756 0.6665669
# summary statistics for the estimates obtained with each method
apply(mres, MARGIN = 2, summary)
#           Sfnc  arima
# Min.    0.3656 0.3656
# 1st Qu. 0.5484 0.5484
# Median  0.6026 0.6026
# Mean    0.6027 0.6027
# 3rd Qu. 0.6568 0.6568
# Max.    0.8664 0.8663
```

I don't recommend this implementation as a substitute to `stats::arima` or other software packages, among other things because its reliability relies on the searching interval (-1,1) set in `optimize`; but it can be helpful for pedagogical purposes and some experimentation.

**References**

[1] D.S.G. Pollock (1999)
*A handbook of time series analysis, signal processing and dynamics*, Academic Press.

Comment: thanx for reference....